# Retrofit2 uploading an image

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to get my Retrofit2 to upload an image to my Flask server, I am not sure why it is not sending the parameter "file" when sending the request.

APIInteface.java

```
@Multipart
@PUT("api/user/update/")
Call<ResponseBody> UpdateUser(@QueryMap Map<String,String> options,
@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("file") RequestBody file);
```

MainActivity:

```
File file = new File(filePath);


        Log.d(TAG,"Calling update function");
        update(file);
    }
}
    public void update(File file) {
        Log.d(TAG,"I got called, yey!");

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.GetAuthClient(token).create(ApiInterface.class);
        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), reqFile);
        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "upload_test");
    data.put("uname",username.getText().toString());
    data.put("fname",firstname.getText().toString());
    data.put("lname",lastname.getText().toString());
    data.put("address",address.getText().toString());
    data.put("password",password.getText().toString());
    data.put("preferance1",String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()));
    data.put("preferance2",String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()));
    data.put("preferance3",String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItem()));
    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.UpdateUser(data,body,name);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why you are sending `@Part("file") RequestBody file`?

Comment: follow this tutorial for file uploading
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap